# How to use a prefix (path) in the href of a tag in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am writing code that links to specific parts of the image.

I can not use if an area tag is available in link_to.

So I want to use the prefix (path) path to href using a tag.

**full code**

```
<%= image_tag "map.png" , usemap: "#map1" %>
  <map name="map1"> 
    <area shape="rect" coords="21,647,173,822" href="/posts/index" title="posts">
  </map>
```

**Try code // not working**

```
href="#{posts_path}"
```

Comment: Try `href="<%= posts_path %>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plain ERB for that. Use it like:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="21,647,173,822" href="<%= posts_path %>" title="posts">
```

Or, you could use [`content_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) and [`tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag) for this too.

```
<%= content_tag(:map, name: 'map1') do %>
  <%= tag.area shape: "rect", coords: "21,647,173,822", href: posts_path, title: "posts" %>
<% end %>
```

Note: [Legacy syntax of `tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag-label-Legacy+syntax)  will be deprecated in future versions of Rails.

```
tag(name, options = nil, open = false, escape = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example

```
<%= image_tag "map.png" , usemap: "#map1" %>
```

or

```
<img usemap="map1" src="map.png"  />

<map name="map1">
    <area href="<%= url_for posts_path %>" title="posts" coords="21,647,173,822" shape="rect" />
    <area href="<%= url_for :controller => "post", :action => "all" %>" alt="All posts" coords="190,0,386,22" shape="rect" />
    <area href="<%= url_for new_resource1_path %>" alt="New resource1" coords="387,0,657,23" shape="rect" />
</map>
```